# Query to get percent of a total using select(count)

Tags: sql, select, count

I'm calculating the change in pain between day 1 and day 2. 
There are two fields, Pain_Admit_Comfort and Pain_48_Hr_Comfort, the options in each is Yes/No.

I need to find everyone that had pain on Admit and is More Comfortable 2 days later.

This is the query. The first two statements return correct numbers. I can't figure out how to divide using the same statements as numerator and denominator.

```
 select 
     (select COUNT (PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C) 
      FROM CASES WHERE PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C='Yes') as Forty_Eight_Hours,

     (SELECT COUNT (PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C)
      FROM CASES WHERE PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C='YES') as Admit_Uncomfort_Yes,

     ((select COUNT (PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C) 
       FROM CASES WHERE PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C='Yes')
      /
     (SELECT COUNT (PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C) 
      FROM CASES WHERE PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C='YES')) AS Percent_Changed

 from CASES
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't spot any immediate problems with your statement but following statement should return the correct results and is perhaps a bit easier to read.

```
SELECT  feh.Forty_Eight_Hours
        , auy.Admit_Uncomfort_Yes
        , Percent_Changed = CAST(feh.Forty_Eight_Hours AS FLOAT) / auy.Admit_Uncomfort_Yes
FROM    (
          SELECT  Forty_Eight_Hours = COUNT(PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C)
          FROM    CASES
          WHERE   PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C = 'Yes' 
        ) feh
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT   Admit_Uncomfort_Yes = COUNT (PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C) 
          FROM     CASES 
          WHERE    PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C = 'Yes'
        ) auy
```

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks, I was pondering on that. The error is fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with Cross Apply, I appreciate your insight and guidance. Two Thumbs Up.

Comment: @Stan - No problem but I do assume you are using SQL Server. If not, you might want to change the CROSS APPLY to an INNER JOIN without actually joining om something.

Answer (score 0):

Your query, and the other answers, are very inefficient (multiple selects).

What you want is called a "pivot", and the most efficient way of coding it using just *one* select over the table (your query uses 4) is as follows:

```
 select
 sum(case when PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Forty_Eight_Hours,
 sum(case when PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Admit_Uncomfort_Yes
 sum(case when PAIN_ADMIT_COMFORT_C = 'Yes' AND PAIN_48_HR_COMFORT_C = 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) as Improved_pain
 FROM CASES
```

I'm not sure what the columns mean - you may need to change a 'YES' to 'NO' etc to get the  "has"/"has not" pain correct.

Comment: Multiple `SELECTS` aren't necessarily inefficient here. The `WHERE` predicates are on different columns. Depends what indexes are on the table.

Comment: @Bohemian - You need to divide the Forty_Eight_Hours value with Admit_Uncomfort_Yes value somehow. I don't see how the query I've presented is inefficient for that? As I see it, best case, two indexes have to be scanned while this is a full table scan (and missing the percentage).

Comment: @Lieven indexes are not used for columns with so few *different* values (here 2: yes and no), so you're looking at a full table scan regardless. My query does one pass. Yours does two. It's that simple. Re the divide, wrap this query in a select to get the divide - the important thing is you have the raw values you need to calculate whatever stats you want. Note that your query, and the OPs, doesn't actually measure what he wants. If you think about it long enough, you'll figure out why.

Comment: @Bohemian - SQL Server will happily use an index on 2 values to do a `COUNT` on. It doesn't have to do any bookmark lookups back to the base table.

Comment: @Bohemian - If you refer to OP's statement *I need to find everyone that had pain on Admit and is More Comfortable 2 days later.*, I think you are right.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh yeah - you're right! Oops! Index-only access would work here, because no other columns are referenced. Although, there would still be *multiple* scans with the other queries, even if they are (very fast) index-only scans.